# ERP with laravel with multiple foreign keys in the intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I am currently in the planning stage of an ERP system with the Laravel Framework, but I have not found a way to make a relationship of 3 tables that I require.
The system would work as interpreted in the following image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqYGW.jpg)

According to the image, how can I insert in the role_user table: the user, role and client with the sync() function?
I would greatly appreciate your support.

Comment: What's the functionality you're looking for?  Given a user ID and a client ID, return what role they are?  The ORM may not natively support that, but seems like something you could do with your own query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to read about Many To Many (Polymorphic) relationships:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

you can use it in role_user table , may be it should be names "model_has_roles" just like this spatie/permission package :
[image]

or you can just use this package ;)
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction